# ng-repeat doesn't work when HTML is altered under $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Directive code:

```
.directive('replace', function($compile) {
      return function (scope, element) {
        element.html(element.html().replace("Hej", "Hey!"));
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
  });
})
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-controller="GreeterController">
     <div replace>Hej <div ng-repeat="e in arr">{{ e }}</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('GreeterController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
}]);
```

[Live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/EAzqPwu6Ly0yUBBx9EJc?p=preview)

As the title says, `ng-repeat` doesn't work when I'm using the directive from above on HTML which contains it.
But once I remove that line which uses `.replace()` command to replace part of HTML then `ng-repeat` starts working for some reason.
Does anyone know where's the actual problem?
I have tried everything and I still seem to not get it why it doesn't work as it should.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is <div replace>? It is not valid HTML, that's for sure.

Comment: Do a transclude instead. `ng-repeat` has very high priority when angular starts compiling a template and gets compiled to comments before anything else happens

Comment: @Siyah that has nothing to do with the issue. While it may not pass an html validator , it will work fine

Comment: @charlietfl how can I achieve that? Can you give me example, please?

Comment: if all you are doing is translations why do you need to replace the whole thing and not isolate the translations with filters or more targeted directive? There are several different translation modules around

Comment: @charlietfl because some elements are differently positioned in different translations because of grammar/sentence structure. Can you give me example with `ng-transclude` for which you said it can be solved with?

Comment: No idea what *"differently positioned"* means or why you can't put the directive on the repeating elements. This whole question seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @charlietfl so you're dodging the question, shifting points and not helping me with the actual problem, and on the top of that accusing me of something... Nice.

Comment: No I am suggesting that the whole approach is wrong but without full context of the exact issue it's hard to help. Also why not do this translation in the initial data parsing instead of in the view?

Comment: @charlietfl It's not wrong. I think I have explained my problem well enough, and if you don't like it you can simply switch to question from someone else.

Comment: well that is your opinion and you don't seem very open minded about it. There are likely numerous other ways to approach whatever the real problem is.

Comment: @charlietfl the real problem is already explained in the question I've asked above, so please leave if you don't want to contribute with anything valuable to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manipulation can also be done in the compile phase:

```
app.directive("replace", function(){
    return {
        compile: function(element){
            element.html(element.html().replace('Hej', 'Hey!'));
            /*return {
                pre: function(scope, element){
                  element.html(element.html().replace('Hej', 'Hey!'));
                }
            }*/
        }
    };
});
```

The original problem was caused because the linking of the `ng-repeat` directive was done before the element with that directive is replaced with the replace operation. The watchers associated with the `ng-repeat` directive then operate on elements that are no longer attached to the visible DOM.

By moving the replace operation to either the compile phase or the preLink phase, the replacing of the element that has the `ng-repeat` directive is done before the `ng-repeat` directive is linked. The watchers associated with `ng-repeat` directive then work with the replaced DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I, however, had to put watcher later which would on trigger recompile the whole directive, and that's why I've put it in `preLink` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should let Angular and its change detection cycle do the HTML manipulation for you, instead of directly changing it yourself.

I've edited your example to use scope bindings to achieve what you wanted:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-compile-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="compileExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('compileExample', [], function($compileProvider) {
    // configure new 'compile' directive by passing a directive
    // factory function. The factory function injects the '$compile'
    $compileProvider.directive('replace', function($compile) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element) {
              scope.greeting = 'Hey!';
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        }
    });
  })
  .controller('GreeterController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    $scope.greeting = 'Hej';
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="GreeterController">
  <div replace>{{greeting}} <div ng-repeat="e in test">{{ e }}</div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Note: I removed "scope: false" as that is the default behaviour.

EDIT:
Since you must replace HTML in place here's a solution with jQuery:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-compile-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
</head>
<body ng-app="compileExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('compileExample', [], function($compileProvider) {
    // configure new 'compile' directive by passing a directive
    // factory function. The factory function injects the '$compile'
    $compileProvider.directive('replace', function($compile) {
        return function (scope, element) {
          $(element).find( ".translation" ).replaceWith("Hey!");
        }
    });
  })
  .controller('GreeterController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="GreeterController">
  <div replace><span class="translation">Hej</span> <div ng-repeat="e in arr">{{ e }}</div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

Comment: I can't do this because I'm using it for translation. I need to replace the whole HTML code with the proper one according to translation.

Comment: @MikiSoft there are better ways to handle translations

Comment: @MikiSoft I edited my comment to show a jQuery solution. If you must edit HTML in place, I would rather use jQuery that re-compiling the directive. I don't even think Angular has access to the HTML of ng-repeat, as it's a template (you can see this when you debug and try to log element.html()) so that's why your initial solution wasn't working.

Comment: @RaresMatei thanks for your effort, but I must use a solution via directive because of the transition that might happen from singular to plural case or vice-versa in live mode.

Comment: @MikiSoft use filter for translation seems better solution

Comment: @tomcater It's not convenient because I need the whole parts of HTML code in order to position its elements according to sentence structure of the each of the languages.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
.directive("replace", function(){
    return {
        compile: function(){
            return {
                pre: function(scope, element){
                    element.html(element.html().replace('Hej', 'Hey!'));
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

[Live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/UxIUVLIqG7pZnDupVwQO?p=preview)